# Return (or not) id in the async method

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

Given the following classes:

```
class Account
{
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public long Id {get; set;}
     ...
}

class AccountModel
{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

If I called this method:

```
async Task AddAccountAsync(AccountModel model)
{
    Account entity = CreateFromModel(model);
    DbContext.Add(entity);
    await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    model.Id = entity.Id;
}
```

model.Id after running (with await) is `-9223372036854775808`.

But if I use this instead:

```
async Task<long> AddAccountAsync(AccountModel model)
{
    Account entity = CreateFromModel(model);
    DbContext.Add(entity);
    await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return entity.Id;
}
```

it returns the **right** value. Why so?

Comment: So if you do this: `var model = new AccountModel(); await AddAccountAsync(model); Console.WriteLine(model.Id);` you get `id == -9223372036854775808`?

Comment: Yes, I have id == -9223372036854775808

Comment: I guess my question is rather, how do you call `AddAccountAsync`? How does the calling code look?

Comment: @CodingYoshi that is incorrect: returning a basic `Task` is perfectly correct, you're confusing this with an `async void` signature, which indeed should be avoided if possible

Answer (score 0):

This code returns a `Task`

```
async Task AddAccountAsync(AccountModel model)
```

So, you would need to `Wait` for the `Task` to finish. Typically like this:

```
var result = AddAccountAsync(model);
result.Wait()
```

Mixing `Wait` and `await` is bit dangerous ! You could typically end up with deadlocks.
The better option would be to use `await` on the `Task`

```
await result
```

After the call finishes, I would expect your `model` object to have the correct value.

The above technique is useful in scenarios where you are calling multiple `async` methods and finally have to wait for all of them to finish.

eg.

```
var result1Task = Method1Async();
var result2Task = Method2Async();
var result3Task = Method3Async();

...
--finally
await Task.WhenAll(result1Task, result2Task, result3Task);
```

Your second method returns an actual value itself

```
async Task<long> AddAccountAsync(AccountModel model)
```

you would typically `await` the above method call and get back the result

```
var id = await AddAccountAsync(model)
```

You would have seen that the comments in your question is asking about: *how exactly you are calling these methods ?*

The way you call these methods will give a clue to why the values are not as per your expectation.

You can explore Stephen Cleary's blog about async/await:
http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

The Async Composition section would be relevant to your query.